# Practice final exam questions, "Data Structures" class

Tags: c++, data-structures

I am working on my practice final for a data structures class, and I have a few questions I was hoping to get help with:

1. ```
   void BST::traverse(Vertex *V)  // post order traversal recursively
   {   
     if (V != NULL) 
       {
         traverse(V->Left);        
         traverse(V->Right);       
         cout << V->elem << endl;     
       }
   }
   ```

   I need to change this to depth-first search.  I believe I have to re-visit the root each recursion to do so, but am confused because then I'd never leave the root.  Perhaps a temporary root?  Not sure!
2. For our linked list implementation, I have to describe 2 occasions when our copy constructor is used.  I know it is called for function calls.  But what's another reason?
3. why do we use big O notation [e.g. O(n^2) instead of saying 2n^2 + 3n + 4).  I know we ignore constants when doing so, but is there more to the answer I can give?
4. Time vs. Space complexities.  The most obvious to me is merge sort vs. quick sort, but can you think of another one in case the test asks for more?  We went over so many in class that I can't believe I can't name more.

Comment: "1. I need to change this to depth-first search" - are you sure it isn't already? It looks like you'll iterate down the `V->Left` completely first.

Comment: hmm yea, perhaps the professor meant breadth first?

Comment: Any function call without a reference or pointer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. It's already a depth-first search if you just add the search code to it.
2. You already have the occasion when a `BST` is *passed by value* to a function as an argument. What is another time that you make a copy of an object? (Hint: one is also related to functions)
3. Because when `n` is large, 2<sup>n</sup> will be much much much larger than anything else in the equation so you just leave constants and everything else out. Big-O notation is definitely not meant to be precise, it's only to let you know how a solution to a problem *scales* as the input grows very large. When `n` gets large enough, the complexity is so huge that the other stuff is dwarfed and it's basically 2<sup>n</sup>.
4. You'll have to be more specific for this one. Are you looking for two algorithms that trade speed for space?

Comment: for 4. It's mostly sorting and searching.  I thought of arrays vs vectors but everything is so inlined now that it's the same thing.

Comment: @user1334943 you could mention arrays vs. linked lists since linked lists are typically more memory-efficient (no wasted space) but are slower to access.

Answer (score 1):

3 big O notation only quotes the dominant term. When n becomes large, this is the most significant part of the result.

4 Consider bubble sort - I used to dislike it as it takes such a long time, but only requires space for one more item.

Comment: And sometimes bubblesort can be done without using any extra space if the items being sorted are integral types